# Python MariaDb Hangs when requesting more than a few rows (say 20+), query works fine with limit 10

Tags: python, mariadb

As described in the headline, tried using lastest mariadb from pypi, and with the latest package from github (https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python)

The query works fine from the script with limit 10, after around that number it starts to just hang when i run curr.execute().

The query (below) runs in milliseconds even with limit 1000 when run in phpmyadmin.

My connect_timeout time in the mariadb.connect params is 30.

```
SELECT terms.term_id, terms.name, tax.taxonomy
FROM wp_terms AS terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tax
ON terms.term_id = tax.term_id
LIMIT 1000;
```

Is there some timeout config I can't find?